# Facebook API match between my id and a friend's id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I know my title seems vague, but that's the best I could do to describe my problem.

I'm using Facebook Graph API for my multiplayer game. When I connect, I get my own Facebook ID, but when I retrieve my friends, I get their encrypt ID.

I would like to inform a player that his friend is online, but I have no matching key to compare to.

How can I match between an encrypted friend ID and a user Facebook ID?

Comment: What are you talking about, “encrypted ids”? Do you actually mean the _tokens_ endpoints such as invitable_friends or taggable_friends return? Those are for the purpose that the name of the endpoint states only, you are not allowed to use them for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out last night, forgot to answer myself... I can only get unencrypted ids using the /friends api, which return only friends who have the app. Fine by me :)